# Wordpress posting array data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I have created a localStorage item which I want to post to the server by using AJAX. I looped through the data of teh localStorage item and push that data to a new array. Now I want to post that new array to the server but my data-fields in the ajax call are returning 0.

```
let shopItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item'));


let array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < shopItem.length; i++){
    let chosen_date = shopItem[i].chosen_date;
    let product_id = shopItem[i].product_id;
    let quantity = shopItem[i].quantity;
    array.push({product_id: product_id, quantity: quantity, chosen_date: chosen_date}); 
}

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
    method: "post",
    data: {
        action: "add_this_shit_to_cart",
        product_id: array.product_id, // LOOP HERE THROUGH ARRAY??
        chosen_date: array.chosen_date, // LOOP HERE THROUGH ARRAY??
        quantity: array.quantity // LOOP HERE THROUGH ARRAY??
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("resp: ", response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

So, do I have to loop through the array again for each field?

In my functions.php I have this:

```
function add_this_shit_to_cart() {
   ob_start();

   $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id'] );
   $chosen_date = intval($_POST['chosen_date'] );
   $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity'] );

    $data = array(
        'product' => $product_id,
        'chosen_date' => $chosen_date,
        'quantity' => $quantity
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_this_shit_to_cart', 'add_this_shit_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_this_shit_to_cart', 'add_this_shit_to_cart' );
```

Can someone help me out?

And yes, basic question: Does this data get stored in the database?

Im new to wordpress so...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.

Have you tried to console.log(shopItem)? From what I understand, shopItem is an object. You cannot loop through an object like what you did here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < shopItem.length; i++){
    let chosen_date = shopItem[i].chosen_date;
    let product_id = shopItem[i].product_id;
    let quantity = shopItem[i].quantity;
    array.push({product_id: product_id, quantity: quantity, chosen_date: chosen_date}); 
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of